# Kernel Configuration: Which Processor Family to choose for 'Celeron M CPU 420' (Core Solo)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to build custom kernel (version 3.12.13) for my old laptop and I am unable to determine the Processor Family from the provided list.

```
( ) 486   
( ) 586/K5/5x86/6x86/6x86MX 
( ) Pentium-Classic   
( ) Pentium-MMX 
( ) Pentium-Pro 
( ) Pentium-II/Celeron(pre-Coppermine)  
( ) Pentium-III/Celeron(Coppermine)/Pentium-III Xeon
( ) Pentium M   
( ) Pentium-4/Celeron(P4-based)/Pentium-4 M/older Xeon  
( ) K6/K6-II/K6-III   
( ) Athlon/Duron/K7   
( ) Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8  
( ) Crusoe
( ) Efficeon
( ) Winchip-C6  
( ) Winchip-2/Winchip-2A/Winchip-3  
( ) AMD Elan
( ) GeodeGX1   
( ) GeodeGX1
( ) Geode GX/LX 
( ) CyrixIII/VIA-C3   
( ) VIA C3-2 (Nehemiah)   
( ) VIA C7
( ) Core 2/newer Xeon
( ) Intel Atom
```

According to [this guide](http://gentoo-en.vfose.ru/wiki/Safe_Cflags/Intel#Intel_Core_Solo.2FDuo.2C_Pentium_Dual-Core_T20xx.2FT21xx), 420 Celeron-M processors are Core Solo based, but I do not know which processor family should I select from above list.
My cpuinfo:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 14
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) M CPU  420  @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x39
cpu MHz     : 1596.033
cache size  : 1024 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx constant_tsc up arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
bogomips    : 3192.06
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

Would someone provide a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you choose Pentium-4/Celeron(P4-based)/Pentium-4 M/older Xeon. In the link you provided, it is mentioned that '-march=prescott' option should be used. And Prescott is Pentium 4, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I will be back with the result.

Comment: I tried several times with that choice but it returns this error : "make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2"

Comment: here is my .config file: http://pastebin.com/0X0LsPsq

Answer (score 0):

You should use Core 2/Newer Xeon option. Your CPU is from Intel Core family.

Answer (score 0):

no. looks to me like pentium M series.