# Atom - compatible processors for a kernel

Tags: x86, chrome-os, chrome-book, atom

Does anyone know any Atom N270-compatible processors (what I mean is not that they run on the same socket, but that they can share a kernel with nothing going wrong). Btw, this also means that they run the same instruction set, right?

(My question is similar to [Kernel Configuration: Which Processor Family to choose for 'Celeron M CPU 420' (Core Solo)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/kernel-configuration-which-processor-family-to-choose-for-celeron-m-cpu-420) , but I'm not making my own kernel; I'm trying to install Chrome OS through http://zzsethzz.blogspot.com/2013/02/install-chromium-upgrade-it-to-chrome.html. Also, the previous link says that the celeron builds should be compatible. Is that true?)